# Function to fetch several dataframes and bind them togheter - R

Tags: r

I have 20 dataframes located in sql view, one for each year. They are named "ZZZ_2017", "ZZZ_2016" etc. I use R and want to write a function that fetch these dataframes, add a column for year and then bind them togheter, returning a single dataframe.

I have created a simple function that does one thing of the above. It fetch a single dataframe and adds a column. (Code attached) I'm thinking if it's possible to loop that function over thoses year I want to bind togheter ( year = c(1997:2017) )... But I dont know how to do.

```
    function(year) {
    df <- tbl(con, paste0("ZZZ_", year)) %>%
    collect()
    df <- df %>% mutate(Year = year)
    }
```

Comment: If you have your dataframes in a list then just use do.call(rbind, list_of_dataframes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try

```
purrr::map_dfr(c(1997:2017), function(year){
                             df <- tbl(con, paste0("ZZZ_", year)) %>% collect()
                             }, .id='year')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
your.df <- as.data.frame(sapply(c(1997:2017), function(year) {
              df <- tbl(con, paste0("ZZZ_", x)) %>%
              collect()
              df <- df %>% mutate(Year = year)
}))
```

Comment: The only thing I changed was that I added as.data.frame(sapply...., otherwise the loop returned a Matrix instead of a dataframe.

Comment: You are right. I should have thought about that. Thank you. I will update the answer.